# How automatically start VPN connection on computer startup in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn, 21.10, autostart

I have a VPN connection with such settings:

[image: vpn config 1]

[image: vpn config 2]

[image: vpn config 3]

How to automatically start VPN connection on computer startup in Ubuntu 21.10?

Now I have to click *Connect* every time.

[image: Connect]

I've read other similar questions, but the answers there don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have 21.10 installed, but in 20.04 you specify this on the settings for the "main connection" you are using, not the VPN.

In my case the "main connection" is a wired one, and on its setting page I could tick the box "automatically connect to VPN" and then specify which one in the box. The VPN connection should already be set up in Network Manager before you do this so that it will be listed in the drop-down box.

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu 21.10 there is no checkbox "Automatically connect to VPN". But your answer helped me. I've executed this command:

`$ nm-connection-editor`

And there I've found the checkbox "Automatically connect to VPN".

Answer (score -1):

you mean you want it to connect everytime your device is being turned ? if yes Windscribe does that even without setting it to start from boot

Comment: I can use windscribe with my own ovpn configuration file in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hello. I looked up Windscribe and it does not appear to do what the OP asked. Nor is it clear it even runs on Ubuntu. Having said that this answer is not really very clear. It would need to say where to get the app from, how to install it and how to start it.