# Firing up my VPN automagically on start-up

Tags: network-manager, vpn, 23.04

I have a VPN configured in NetworkManager using `nm-connection-editor`.

Boot and all is fine and my wired is up, and if I then click the VPN in the thing at top right then it starts perfectly.

If I use `nm-connection-editor` to tell the wired connection to automatically connect to the VPN, then on boot I get no wired and obvs no VPN.

Someone gifted me this line which works perfectly to start the VPN from the CLI:

```
nmcli con up [myVPNname]
```

Now, how can I stick that in as a `start-up` script which will always run on boot *after* the wired is up and running?

Comment: How about ticking the box in Network Manager? https://askubuntu.com/a/1399656/243321 Or is that what you mean by nm-connection-editor and it didn't work? If so, you can put your script in /etc/network/if-up.d

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that might have been clear from the original post. I believe I said: "If I use nm-connection-editor to tell the wired connection to automatically connect to the VPN, then on boot I get no wired and obvs no VPN." Always looking to learn.